# "one to many" and "many to one" associations realized by own entity; unique constraint violated

Tags: jpa

I want to realize a mapping as follows. I have a some products and articles. To one product are many articles associated. Further this relation has special properties like a return code. So the association table should look like this.

```
Product_FK | Article_FK | return code
       1   |    1       |      0
       1   |    1       |      1
       1   |    2       |      1
```

At the moment I have realized this with two associations. A "one (Product) to many (Relation Table)" and a "many (Realation Table) to one (Article)" association.

The entities are annotated as fallows:

Product entity:

```
@Entity(name = "product")
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class ProductDTO implements BaseEntityDTO {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -6613561719098236228L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "PRODUCT_PK")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_pk_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_pk_seq", sequenceName = "product_pk_seq",   allocationSize = 1)
   protected Long pk;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="product")
   private List<ProductArticleRelationDTO> product2article = new ArrayList<ProductArticleRelationDTO>();
  ...
  }
```

ProductArticleRelation entity:

```
@Entity(name = "productArticleRelation")
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_2_ARTICLE")
public class ProductArticleRelationDTO implements BaseEntityDTO {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -1134854397447263839L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "PRODUCT_2_ARTICLE_PK")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product2article_pk_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "product2article_pk_seq", sequenceName = "product2artikle_pk_seq", allocationSize = 1)
   protected Long pk;

   @Override
   public Long getPk() {
    return pk;
   }

   @Override
   public void setPk(long pk) {
    this.pk = Long.valueOf(pk);
   }

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_FK")
   private ProductDTO product = null;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_FK")
   private ArticleDTO article = null;

   @Column
   private int returnCode;
     ...
 }
```

Article entity:

```
@Entity(name = "article")
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
public class ArticleDTO implements BaseEntityDTO {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4397348044985703865L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ARTICLE_PK")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "article_pk_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "article_pk_seq", sequenceName = "article_pk_seq", allocationSize = 1)
   protected Long pk;

   @Override
   public Long getPk() {
    return pk;
   }

   @Override
   public void setPk(long pk) {
    this.pk = Long.valueOf(pk);
   }

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "article")
   private final List<ProductArticleRelationDTO> product2article = new ArrayList<ProductArticleRelationDTO>();

 ...
 }
```

I'm pretty sure that the annotations are wrong. I get a unique constraint violation if I want to persist a product which some productArticleRelations are added.

```
  for(ProductArticleRelationDTO relation : newProduct2Article) {
    product.addProduct2Article(relation);

  if(!em.contains(product))
        if(product.getPK() == null)
            em.persist(product);
        else 
        product = em.merge(product);
  else
    em.flush();
```

The Exception:

```
    Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: Unique Constraint (BC7_BPV.PK_ARTICLE) violated
    Error Code: 1
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(bc7.bpv.common.dto.ProductDTO@38f2f)
```

What I'm not so really sure about is, if I need the productArticleRelation entity. That means is it possible to handle this kind of realtion with one association "one (product) to many (aricles)" and a special join table which has the "return code" as a attribute?

edit: I have forgot, this relation should be bidirectional.

My Tables in the database are as fallows (to simplify only important columns are shown):

PRODUCT:

```
 | PRODUCT_PK | ... |
```

ARTICLE:

```
 | ARTICLE_PK | ... |
```

PRODUCT_2_ARTICLE:

```
 | PRODUCT_2_ARTICLE_PK | PRODUCT_FK | ARTICLE_FK | RETURNCODE
```

Comment: include the SQL log, ensure you don't have two copies of the Article

Comment: Where can I get the the SQL log? I'm using a glassfish app server.

Comment: Okay found it (set logging level in persistence.xml).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the SQL log :-) Anyway is was something different, the annotations are correct and it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: `@JoinColumn` should be annotated on the owning side, i.e in `ProductArticleRelationDTO` only. Remove it completely from `Product` and `Article`. To map the collections, you should use `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="property")`, where property is the java name for the mapping property. In this case, either "product" or "article" depending on the class.

About the necessity of ProductArticleRelationDTO: you need it as long as you need to access the return code in java. You could skip it if it was only a ManyToMany mapping table and map Product to Article directly, but this is not the case now.

Try this and comment if it doesn't solve your problems.

Comment: I need to have access to the return code. Thanks for your solution. I will try it.

Comment: I have add the table like they are in the database

Comment: do you get the same exception?

Comment: My question is up to date, so yes.